# How do I change the default follow-up time for outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to set the default follow up time to 6:30 am (tagging items to alert before my work day starts at 7 am)

I am scheduling emails to alert me, by using the "follow up" & "add reminder" buttons on Outlook 2010.  After searching the web, I found that it defaults to one hour before the end of your work day.

There is some suggestions that changing the default time for "tasks" (second screen shot") may have an impact, but even after setting this, closing and re-opening outlook I am still getting the 2:30 default time.

[image: Follow up pop-up]

[image: Task customize]

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found for you.

> You need to change your quick click default to anything except Today
>   and the reminder will default to the start of your workday. Right
>   click on the flag column and choose Set Quick Click to change it.

So, to set the reminder to 30 minutes before your workday starts, you will need to adjust your calendar work hours.

[image]

You may find this source article very helpful; [Understanding the Flag for Follow Up Reminder Time](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/understanding-outlooks-flag-for-follow-up-reminder-time/).

Comment: We have a corporate email server, if I change my work day it will make arraigning meetings problematic.  I am looking for an option that does not require changing the work day.  Now it defaults to 2:30 because my work day ends at 3:30

Comment: Are you setting the flag for "Today"? It will set the reminder for an hour before the end of the workday if the default time has passed. So, if you set the flag for "Tomorrow" it set it to the start of the day. Does it still sets it to 2:30?

Comment: I am picking a date in the future (several weeks) if you select tomorrow it does not give you a chance to set the date, if you pick custom, it still selects 2:30 and to get the option to change the time, you need to check the reminder box. You have to select "add reminder" to modify the time without extra button clicks.